# Using RANKX in PowerBI DAX

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, rank, powerquery

I am a PowerBI newbie and I have been playing with DAX functions, more specifically, the RANKX function. Here is my data set:

```
+----------+-------------------------------------+-----------------+----------+
| Category |            Sub Category             |      Date       | My Value |
+----------+-------------------------------------+-----------------+----------+
| A        |              A1                     |      2018-01-01 |        2 |
| A        |              A2                     |      2018-01-02 |        4 |
| A        |              A3                     |      2018-01-03 |        6 |
| A        |              A4                     |      2018-01-04 |        6 |
| B        |              B1                     |      2018-01-05 |       21 |
| B        |              B2                     |      2018-01-06 |       22 |
| B        |              B2                     |      2018-01-07 |       23 |
| C        |              C1                     |      2018-01-08 |       35 |
| C        |              C2                     |      2018-01-09 |       35 |
| C        |              C3                     |      2018-01-10 |       35 |
+----------+-------------------------------------+-----------------+----------+
```

And below is my code:

```
Rank all rows as Column = 
    RANKX(
        'Table',
        'Table'[My Value]
        )
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

> A single value for column 'My Value' in table 'Table' cannot be
>   determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column
>   that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as
>   min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you calculating a column or a measure?

Comment: @RADO having a column that ranks all the "My Value" is what would be ideal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your formula, you just put it in a wrong place.

There are 2 ways you can write DAX formulas in PowerBI:

- as a calculated column
- as a measure

[image]

The difference is critical, you need to learn it if you want to use PowerBI.

The formula you wrote is for calculated columns. If you create it as a measure, you will get an error. To fix the problem, go to tab "Model", click "New Column", paste your code and it should work.

If you need RANKX as a measure, Chrisoffer has given you a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a mesure to sum "My value" column:

```
Sum value = SUM(Table[My value])
```

Then use this measure to get your rank:

```
Rank all rows as Column = 
    RANKX(ALL(Table);[Sum value])
```

This will give you the rank of each sub category.

Comment: thanks, I am not getting any error thank you... but I dont see any additional column for the ranking.. was I suppose to see that? how should I use the "Rank all rows as Column" variable?

Comment: Why it doesn't work when I use RANKX(ALL(Table);SUM(Table[My value]))?